# My 3 y old DD is refusing to sit on potty/toilet after a bad spell of constipation?

Tags: toddler, potty-training

My 3 year old daughter is fully potty/toilet trained apart from wearing a nappy for bedtime. She had constipation recently which was very painful for her. This has cleared now, but she is still refusing to sit on the potty or toilet and holding in her wee until it literally burst out of her. I have asked if she wants to wear a nappy and she refuses that as well. Please help!!!

Comment: Painful BMs have a way of scaring children into holding it in. If you search the site, you might get some helpful hits. If you can't search, stool softeners and lots of liquids will eventually sort it out.